# Attempt to execute rgb2gray script as a function

Tags: image, matlab

I am doing image segmentation of round objects that have similar color to their background. The image is RGB but the RGB values give tones of gray, notice even though the image looks gray it is not in grayscale. In the segmentation process I have to apply gradient filters and opening and closing by reconstruction in order to separate the round objects from the background before making the binary mask that I will use for segmentation. Some of the functions I used in this process accept 2D arrays inputs only. In fact, binarization of the image itself can only be done in 2D array inputs, not in RGB images which are a 3D array. So, I am trying to convert my RGB image which looks gray but is not in grayscale first. But, I get the following error form MATLAB when I use the rgb2gray function:

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT rgb2gray as a
>   function:C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\rgb2gray.m
>
> Error in Mask_Biophysics (line 2) Frame= rgb2gray(Frame1);

Does anyone what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Never knew that I can guess your code and image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have created a script in `C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB` named `rgb2gray.m` which hides the default implementation of `rgb2gray`. Try removing or renaming this script file and run your program again. It is always a good idea to avoid giving files the same name as built-in MATLAB commands.

Comment: Thank you. That was the case I had named a previous file with the same name of the function. Now, If I can aska  follow up question. When I ran my program I got second error from the use of the same rgb2gray function. The error is: Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 77)
MAP must be a m x 3 array.

Error in rgb2gray (line 52)
[X, threeD] = parse_inputs(X);

Error in Mask_Biophysics (line 2)
Frame= rgb2gray(Frame1);

Comment: Please post your question as a new one and provide a link to this question if needed. If an answer solves your problem, please accept it. Other people may benefit from your question and the accepted solution.